# HashMap of ArrayList causing nullpointerexception

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a HashMap of ArrayLists for values but the HashMap remains empty when I add the ArrayLists and then throws an NullPointerException when I try to get() the ArrayList. VERY confused.

```
Random rand = new Random();
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> hands = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> deck = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
    hands.put(x+SUITS[x], new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}       
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<13;y++){
            int randCard = rand.nextInt(52)+1;
            if(!deck.containsKey(randCard)){
                deck.put(randCard, true);

                hands.get(x+cardSuit(randCard)).add(randCard);

            }else y--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty hard to troubleshoot without being able to see the _cardSuit()_ method, but it's obvious that there is no value mapped to the key you're using when you get.

Comment: Looking at your code there is no reason to expect that any of the keys you try to dereference will be present.  They keys you use when you _put_ are completely different than the keys you use when you _get_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here cardSuit(randCard) is returning something that is not in the map.

You are putting  `x+""`  as the keys.

But when you are retrieving you are using this:

`x+"something"`

Comment: Please try to use code formatting for code-like things, not entire answers that are mostly not code.

Answer (score 5):

You're putting values into the map with keys that look like this:

```
someInt + ""
```

You're getting values from the map with keys that look like this:

```
someInt + cardSuit(randCard)
```

Unless cardSuit always returns an empty string, those are going to be different keys.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it while debugging but that is not the problem. The HashMap never increases in size during the execution of code and remains at size=0. Sorry for not clarifying

Comment: @WarrenGreen - That's absolutely impossible.  Your code must put values in at least the map named _Hands_.  Your for loop is sure to execute and (unless it's throwing an Exception on the first iteration) it will put a value in the map on every iteration.

Comment: @WarrenGreen - You should add debug statements (better yet use a debugger) to see what your code is doing.  Each time you put something into a map, print out the key and the value.  Before you call `Map.get`, you should print the key and check to see if the element exists by calling `Map.containsKey`.